# Ubuntu as a separate OS v/s Wubi

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-systems, linux-distributions, wubi

Due to some hardware problem, I am unable to use both my DVD drive and the bootable USB stick to install Ubuntu as a separate OS alongside Windows 7. I came across WUBI. I was wondering if there would be any performance or usability difference when using Ubuntu through Wubi. Will I able to do all that I can do on Ubuntu when installed as a separate OS? 
P.S. I have an i5-4690k 3.5 GHz processor and 4 GB of RAM

Comment: Everything about WUBI you need to know is [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide).  Word to wise, WUBI only supports up to Ubuntu 12.10 which isn't supported. WUBI was discontinued and shouldn't be used under any situation.

Comment: Another option in your case would be to install Ubuntu directly from the .iso with VMware Player. I run several Linux distros like that. Here is a tutorial I made that also applies to Ubuntu. ==> https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=475A0A48CA6D4035&id=475A0A48CA6D4035%211853